# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in IntelliJ using Maven

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, intellij-idea

I wanted to try a sample JDBC exercise, so I created a project using Maven Quickstart Archetype.

```
public class App {
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb";

    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "password";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

            System.out.println("Creating statement...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
            . . . .
            . . . .
```

When I try to run it,

```
mvn package
java -cp target/simple-java-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.test.App
```

I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.App.main(App.java:24)
```

But if I just try to run the application directly, like, running it as an application in IntelliJ, it works fine.
I have tried adding a jar, but it still doesn't work.

What am I lacking in here?

Comment: I'll guess that you aren't creating a fat JAR with the dependencies using the Maven shade plug in.

Comment: You don't even need the `Class.forName()` line, since 2007, but you do need the MySQL JDBC driver JAR file on your classpath. You should run it using the -jar option, not the -cp option, and ensure the Manifest Main-Class entry specifies `com.test.App`. That way, the Manifest's own Class-Path entry takes effect. Your way, it doesn't.

Comment: Why are you not running your code directly from intellij?

Comment: Java -cp include MySQL jar also. It is working from IDE all the jars were in classpath IDE.

Comment: actually i have figured it out. i need a plugin to copy dependencies
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html
 
then
`java -cp target/* com.test.App`

Comment: You can answer your own question with the details how you've resolved it, for others. Putting these in comments doesn't really help!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I could solve it by adding the MySQL connector [Maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java). (Only plugin I have added is Tomcat Maven plugin.)

And you don't need `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` any more.

- Java version: 10.0.1
- Intellij IDEA version: 2018.1.8 (Community Edition)